About CSS selector with React.js
this is my first question here and I am very new for React.
I would like to change the color "Darkmode" and "LightMode" by useContext of react with simple button called "Change DarkMode", when I see the developer tool.Once I press this button, we can see classname is actually working, so it changes from "app false" to "app dark-theme" but the color is not changed. So I guess css selector is not good ?
Classname before
classname after
In App.jsx,I write
function App() {
  const { darkblue } = useDarkBlue();

  return (
    <div className={`app ${darkblue && "dark-theme"}`}> 
// Here is for change classname from defalut to "dark-theme" and this class name is connected with CSS.
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function AppWithProvider() {
  return (
    <DarkBlueProvider>
      <App />
    </DarkBlueProvider>
  );
}

in CSS,
:root {
  --font-family-title: "PaytoneOne-Regular";
  --font-family-text: "JosefinSans-Regular", sans-serif;
  --font-color: black;
  --background-gradient: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #73bde6,
    #8ed6d7,
    #adeae434
  );
  --background-gradient-false: linear-gradient(to bottom, #07399c, #95aadc);
}

.buttonDarkMode {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh-117px);
}

app false {
  background: var(--background-gradient);
}


I tried changing the className with "div app false" and "div app dark-theme"

You don't have any css selectors with 'dark-theme' ?

'app' and 'false' are classes, then the css selectors should be '.app' and '.false'

To select the classname "app false", you should use the css selector .app.false, like so:
.app.false {
  background: var(--background-gradient-false);
}

Here is the difference between different selectors:
app false: select a tag false that is a child of tag app
<app>
   <false /> /* <- this tag will get selected */
</app>

app.false: select a tag app with classname false
<app classname="false" />

.app.false: select any tag with classname app and classname false:
<div classname="app false" />, <div classname="false app" />, <span classname="app false" />... would all get selected.
For more information on CSS selectors, you can read the W3Schools reference for the basics and the MDN docs for more details.
As for your specific issue, I would advise you to not use false as a class. You can instead use .app as your default theme, and .app.dark-theme as your dark theme. To combine classes, I would also advise you to use clsx, that you can install via npm install clsx. Here is an example of the result:
React
import clsx from 'clsx';

function App() {
  const { darkblue } = useDarkBlue();

  return (
    <div className={clsx("app", darkblue && "dark-theme")}> 
// Here is for change classname from defalut to "dark-theme" and this class name is connected with CSS.
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function AppWithProvider() {
  return (
    <DarkBlueProvider>
      <App />
    </DarkBlueProvider>
  );
}

CSS
:root {
  --font-family-title: "PaytoneOne-Regular";
  --font-family-text: "JosefinSans-Regular", sans-serif;
  --font-color: black;
  --background-gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom, #07399c, #95aadc);
  --background-gradient-dark: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #73bde6,
    #8ed6d7,
    #adeae434
  );
}

.buttonDarkMode {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh-117px);
}

.app {
  background: var(--background-gradient);
}

.app.dark-theme {
  background: var(--background-gradient-dark);
}

Wish you the best with your learning journey in web & React!
